# Facebook Graph API requests on page events returns empty result array

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

I created a PHP script a year ago, that requests the events from a Facebook page, and it still works fine- except for one page and only since recently.

```
$config = array();
$config[ 'appId' ] = '468554113184955';
$config[ 'secret' ] = 'APP_SECRET';
$config[ 'fileUpload' ] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook( $config );

$res = $facebook->api( '/Stadtpalais/events?fields=id,name,start_time,description,updated_time,picture.type(large)', 'GET' );
```

I also tried the request with another app ending with the same result, so I think retrieving a new app secret wouldn't help.

The script is just working with `appId` and `secret`, but without any user login. Try the [Graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=stadtpalais/events) with any app access token like '468554113184955|APP_SECRET' (use your own ID and secret) to reproduce the error. Change the page to any other page and it will work.

Can page admins prevent these public requests through settings? (I haven't found one yet.)
Could an event title or description or whatever trigger an error so that Facebook sends an empty array?

Some time ago I read that Facebook might force a user login to request the events, but since it's working fine with other pages, I'd think that hasn't happened yet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can now answer my own question: It's due to the page setting

```
Age Restrictions = Alcohol-related
```

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion. Did you manage to find a way around it?
Apparently if the logged in User has access then it 'should' work so I need to see if I can change the access token or something but Graph API is new to me.